# disable one or more item in repeat list in ui select

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I need to disable one or more options in ui-select repeat

Here's an array which I want to repeat

```js
$scope.list = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']
```

and here's a select function

```js
<ui-select ng-model="item"
           on-select="changeItem()"
           ng-disabled="isReadOnly()" required>

    <ui-select-match class="ui-select-match">
        <span ng-bind="$select.selected"></span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices class="ui-select-choices"
                       repeat="item in list">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <span ng-bind="item"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

And for example I want to disable `item2` and `item4`

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable some of the options you can use [`ui-disable-choice`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select-choices#user-content-example-disable-choices) attribute together with [`ui-select-choices`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select-choices) to pass an expression to check.

In your case something like `ui-disable-choice="item == 'item2' || item == 'item4'"` should work.

Comment: This option doesn't work(( 

This error occurs: TypeError: Cannot create property '_uiSelectChoiceDisabled' on string 'item1'

Comment: @AndriiBlinov This is an issue with older versions of `ui-select` and looks like it was fixed in latest versions. The problem was that the result of the expression was stored as a property of the item like `item._uiSelectChoiceDisabled = isDisabled;`, that is why you are getting the mentioned error. You can try updating `ui-select` or you can use a list of items like `$scope.list = [{value : 'item1'}, {value : 'item2'}, {value : 'item3'}, {value : 'item4'}]` and than use it in the view like `repeat="item.val as item in list" ui-disable-choice="item.val == 'item2' || item.val == 'item4'"`.

Comment: oh. I'm sorry.  I've forgot to answer, Yes it worked, I used an object. Thanks)